# How do I resolve a build issue with skipping maven unit tests?

Tags: maven, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

Yesterday I upgraded my "Mule Server Runtime" in Anypoint Studio to "4.2.2 EE 7.3.5.202101082244". I am now getting an error trying to build a project that used to build successfully:

```
mvn clean package -nsu -DskupMunitTests has encountered a problem.
```

This command also appears in the 'Edit configuration and launch" popup window when I use "Run as Mule Application (configure). I don't have any Maven unit tests and have never seen this error before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I downloaded a command line version of Maven and "IT" (not the built in version) told me that there was a problem with one of my flows. The issue had NOTHING to do with the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that your issue is with your flows as you mentioned. But I will suggest here always to use the latest version of Anypoint studio.

Thanks